# Copy texture sub rectangles using shaders and rtt

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to write a function which shall take a sub-rectangle from a 2D texture (non power-of-2) and copy it to a destination sub-rectangle of an output 2D texture, using a shader (no glSubImage or similar). 
Also the source and the destination may not have the same size, so I need to use linear filtering (or even mipmap).

```
void CopyToTex(GLuint dest_tex,GLuint src_tex,
               GLuint src_width,GLuint src_height,
               GLuint dest_width,GLuint dest_height,
               float srcRect[4],
               GLuint destRect[4]);
```

Here srcRect is in normalized 0-1 coordinates, that is the rectangle [0,1]x[0,1] touch the center of every border pixel of the input texture.

To achieve a good result when the input and source dimensions don't match, I want to use a `GL_LINEAR` filtering.

I want this function to behave in a coherent manner, i.e. calling it multiple times with many subrects shall produce the same result as one invocation with the union of the subrects; that is the linear sampler should sample the exact center of the input pixel.

Moreover, if the input rectangle fit exactly the destination rectangle an exact copy should occur.
This seems to be particularly hard.

What I've got now is something like this:

```
//Setup RTT, filtering and program

float vertices[4] = { 
      float(destRect[0]) / dest_width * 2.0 - 1.0,
      float(destRect[1]) / dest_height * 2.0 - 1.0, 
      //etc..
};

float texcoords[4] = {
      (srcRect[0] * (src_width - 1) + 0.5) / src_width - 0.5 / dest_width,
      (srcRect[1] * (src_height - 1) + 0.5) / src_height - 0.5 / dest_height,
      (srcRect[2] * (src_width - 1) + 0.5) / src_width + 0.5 / dest_width,
      (srcRect[3] * (src_height - 1) + 0.5) / src_height + 0.5 / dest_height,
};

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(texcoords[0], texcoords[1]);
glVertex2f(vertices[0], vertices[1]);

glTexCoord2f(texcoords[2], texcoords[1]);
glVertex2f(vertices[2], vertices[1]);

//etc...
glEnd();
```

To write this code I followed the information from [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Rasterization) page.

This seems to work as intended in some corner cases (exact copy, copying a row or a column of one pixel).

My hardest test case is to perform an exact copy of a 2xN rectangle when both the input and output textures are bigger than 2xN.

I probably have some problem with offsets and scaling (the trivial ones don't work).

Comment: "*My hardest test case is to perform an exact copy of a 2xN rectangle when both the input and output textures are bigger than 2xN.*" What happens in that case?

Comment: @NicolBolas The input pixels are merged. My input is a checkboard texture, the output is a faded checkboard.

Comment: Do you mean blurred check-board? it could be related to down-sampling and filtering. you should show the whole initialization of `vertices[4]` especially that `glVertex2f(vertices[2], vertices[1])` seems wrong. isn't `glVertex2f(vertices[2], vertices[3])`

Comment: I think GL_NEAREST may actually get you cleaner more accurate results.

Comment: @JustinMeiners the whole point of this thing is to use linear filtering.

Comment: @sbabbi that seems like a strange "whole point" GL_LINEAR is very simple, and often doesn't provide the best results, but ok.

Comment: It sounds like he's trying to use bilinear filtering to do the dirty work of smoothly rescaling the image :) But what he doesn't realize is bilinear filtering in OpenGL is not standardized (in terms of sample weights). So this may not produce "coherent" results...

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The `0.5/tex_width` part in the definition of the texcoords was wrong.
An easy way to work around is to completely remove that part.

```
float texcoords[4] = {
      (srcRect[0] * (src_width - 1) + 0.5) / src_width,
      (srcRect[1] * (src_height - 1) + 0.5) / src_height,
      (srcRect[2] * (src_width - 1) + 0.5) / src_width,
      (srcRect[3] * (src_height - 1) + 0.5) / src_height
};
```

Instead, we draw a smaller quad, by offsetting the vertices by:

```
float dx = 1.0 / (dest_rect[2] - dest_rect[0]) - epsilon;
float dy = 1.0 / (dest_rect[3] - dest_rect[1]) - epsilon;

// assume glTexCoord for every vertex 
glVertex2f(vertices[0] + dx, vertices[1] + dy);
glVertex2f(vertices[2] - dx, vertices[1] + dy);
glVertex2f(vertices[2] - dx, vertices[3] - dy);
glVertex2f(vertices[0] + dx, vertices[3] - dy);
```

In this way we draw a quad which pass from the exact center of every border pixel. 
Since OpenGL may or may not draw the border pixels in this case, we need the epsilons.

I believe that my original solution (don't offset vertex coords) can still work, but need a bit of extra math to compute the right offsets for the texcoords.